# Uninstall a netbeans 7.0.1 plugin, netbeans doesn't start

Tags: python, plugins, netbeans, uninstallation, netbeans-7

Netbeans 7.0.1 on Vista doesn't start after installing python plugin.
How do I uninstall plugins manually?

Is there a command line argument to start netbeans without plugins? If not, this should be easy to add to netbeans :-)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Here is how I solved it in 8.0.2 (without losing all settings and modules).

Go to '**C:\Users\yourAccount\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Modules**' and delete the faulty (last installed plugin).

If you have several installed versions, have a look in their '\config\Modules' as well.

Start the Netbeans :)

Answer (score 2):

Open Net Beans Plugin Manager From Tools => Plugins

Now go to Installed Plugin and right click on user installed plugin and then deactivate it.

that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an alternate user directory:

```
netbeans.exe --userdir c:\temp\myTestHome\
```

If this works then something has gone wrong in your .netbeans folder in your user home directory.

Delete the %userhome%.netbeans directory, and everything should be as it was when you initially installed netbeans. 
Note that this will also remove all personal settings you may have made to netbeans.