# Netbeans 8.2 Python Plugin

Tags: python, plugins, netbeans-8.2

I just downloaded the most recent version of NetBeans 8.2 with the JDK, specifically the Windows x64 version [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html).

The issue I'm having is when I open it and go to Available Plugins, there's no option for Python plugins.

[No Python Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf25j.png)

Anyone know if there's a python plugin I can find externally to use with this? Looking in the Installed Plugins, there's no indication of a pre-existing Python plugin, btw.

Comment: Update for 2023: Oracle no longer provides downloads for older version of Netbeans (older than like 10 or 11), and plugin URLs are outdated. You can download Netbeans 8.2 (compatible w/ the python plugin) from archive.org: [ https://archive.org/details/jdk-8u111-nb-8_2 ] and you can download the NBPython plugin from the official website: [ http://nbpython.org ] or from sourceforge: [ https://sourceforge.net/projects/nbpython ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no official plugin for 8.2.  A beta is in development (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/NBPython).
You can download the and install the 8.1 version (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/61688/python).
1) Unzip
2) Start Netbeans IDE 8.2
3) Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> [Add Plugins ...] open the extracted files
4) install all plugins
5) Restart IDE

Best of luck cause your mileage may very ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you!

Comment: I installed the plugin for 8.1 and then netbeans became unresponsive, even after restarting netbeans. I guess my mileage varied. Back up and running now thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083470/1295595

Comment: An advantage with NetBeans is that you can have multiple versions installed on the same OS, just maintain your old '8.1' just for Python purposes as a newer plugin is being built while you use your newer NetBeans versions for your other programming languages.

Comment: Update for 2023: Oracle no longer provides downloads for older version of Netbeans, and plugin URLs are outdated. You can download Netbeans 8.2 (compatible w/ the python plugin) from archive.org: [https://archive.org/details/jdk-8u111-nb-8_2] and you can download the NBPython plugin from the official website: [ http://www.nbpython.org ]